# How to stop end shiny session by closing the browser

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have a shiny app that I would like to end the session every time, I close the browser. I researched around and most developers proposed adding this snippet on my server.

```
session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })
```

A minimal example is provided below;

```
rm(list=ls())

library(shiny)

doshiny <- function() {
  app=shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      textInput("textfield", "Insert some text", value = "SomeText")
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
      session$onSessionEnded(function() {
        stopApp()
      })
    }
  )
  runApp(app)
}

openshiny <- function() {
  doshiny()
  print("Finished.")
}

openshiny()
```

the problem with this example I keep asking myself where should I place my other the other lines in the server? for instance, if I want to plot a histogram which way do I write my server?

is it

```
    server = function(input, output, session) {
      session$onSessionEnded(function() {
       hist(data)
        stopApp()
      })
    }
  )
```

or

```
    server = function(input, output, session) {
     hist(data)
      session$onSessionEnded(function() {
        stopApp()
      })
    }
  )

 I am just seeking a more working example
```

Comment: best guess : In the server. Why do you want to draw an histogram if the session is ended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to plot your histogram while the session is active, take the second option. As mentioned by @Waldi the first option plots your histogram when the session is ended, and the user will thus never see the histogram. See here an example of the two options:

First option: we never see the table

```
rm(list=ls())

library(shiny)

doshiny <- function() {
    app=shinyApp(
        ui = fluidPage(
            textInput("textfield", "Insert some text", value = "SomeText"),
            dataTableOutput('table')
        ),
        server = function(input, output, session) {

            session$onSessionEnded(function() {
                output$table <- renderDataTable(iris)
                stopApp()
            })
        }
    )
    runApp(app)
}

openshiny <- function() {
    doshiny()
    print("Finished.")
}

openshiny()
```

Second option: we see the table

```
rm(list=ls())

library(shiny)

doshiny <- function() {
    app=shinyApp(
        ui = fluidPage(
            textInput("textfield", "Insert some text", value = "SomeText"),
            dataTableOutput('table')
        ),
        server = function(input, output, session) {
            output$table <- renderDataTable(iris)
            session$onSessionEnded(function() {

                stopApp()
            })
        }
    )
    runApp(app)
}

openshiny <- function() {
    doshiny()
    print("Finished.")
}

openshiny()
```

Comment: I compiled a shinyapp to a rinno executable file. I noticed that when using the app  and i happen to close the widow/browser starting the app again doesnt work.  I guess by closing the browser the app was not stoping. To cut long story short i was looking how to use  the above function to close the app when then i exit the browser.  Your answer helped me out